# How to select and deselect image from a gallery by clicking using javascript

Tags: javascript, toggle, image-gallery

The code selects an image from gallery but can't deselect it shows only alert message while image clicked twice:

```js
const selectItem = (event, img) => {
  let element = event.target;
  element.classList.add('added');
  let item = sliders.indexOf(img);
  if (item === -1) {
    sliders.push(img);
  } else {
    alert('already added');
  }
}
```

Comment: First check if image is already in sliders array. If it exists then remove it before pushing to sliding array.

Comment: can you help me with code pls !!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
const selectItem = (event, img) => {
  let element = event.target;
  element.classList.add('added');
  let item = sliders.indexOf(img);
  if (item === -1) {
    sliders.push(img);
  } else {
    
    sliders.pop(img);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but main problem is, i want to select or deselect image by clicking like toggle, if i click image once it will select and if i click twice it will deselect